# What is the difference between a console and non-console terminal session?

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

Log in to a server with remote access in console session and non console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console session is the console session - the physical Screen. Only one logged on user allowed, regardless of Password, shared between remote Desktop AND THE LOCAL SCREEN. This is a "last Resort" Login, but also one to make sure it is only you. You log on and someone is logged on locally, he gets logged out (actually you throw him out).

Non-console are virtual sessions, max 2 without terminal Server, both have to be admins. THis means total of 3 admins can work on a Server same time.